# How can I fast travel?

Tags: muramasa-the-demon-blade

I feel like all I'm doing is backtracking, and I need to backtrack to one of the first levels because I didn't buy something I need. Is there any way to fast travel to another area once I've been there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways, likely don't help as much as you want though.

1) Bronze mirror - returns you to the last shrine visited.

2) Boats and the carriages which charge a fee.

3) Warp between shrines after you beat the game.